# windows 7 snap feature

Tags: windows-7

Can you snap two windows in Windows 7 but also connect them so when you alt+tab through windows both of them show?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want...

Comment: When you switch a window to the foreground, he wants a window he linked to that one to appear.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior does not exist as far as I know of...

The closest you can get is to use Virtual Desktop software, see for example: http://vdm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can enable this feature by following these simple steps:

1. open control panel
2. open ease of access center
3. click on make the mouse easier to use
4. turn off the highlighted option and don't forget to click on apply button

[image]